# Premature end of data in tag html line 3

Tags: magento, soap

I want to login into Magento from SOAPui but i got this error

```
<faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
     <faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.mysite1.com/index.php/api/V2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : Premature end of data in tag html line 3</faultstring>
```

I have enabled WSDL Cache in magento admin panel.

Please help